# Combining Cells from Query If They Have The Same Key?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've been working on a vendor database for my company that's autopopulated by a google form. I've gotten it set up so that there's a tab that will query and parse information based on the type of vendor people are using and where they are looking for a vendor.

I'm now trying to figure out how to combine entries that are for the same vendor into the same row so that if someone enters in a vendor saying they used them more recently, it'll show a list of the times the vendor has been used. Eventually I'd also like it to merge duplicate names/numbers for vendor contact, but I feel like I can figure that out once I figure out how to either concatenate or text join the Job #'s / Dates.

As of now, I'm working in an isolated version of the database that has:

1. A "Raw Form Data" tab that has all form entries
2. a "Vendor Database" tab that uses a query to bring in entries and do a 
   =unique(QUERY('Raw Form Data'!$B$2:$M, "Select * Order By B, E, D, C"))
   This tab also marks the lines with a sorting number for the selector tab and currently a "Index Key" which is just a concatenation of the Vendor Name, City, and State.
3. A Selector Tab that uses a query to sort through the data and reorder based on the sorting number and location.

The bottom line:

I'd like to make a new tab that has copies in all rows that has the same "Index Key" but then jointext() all cells in a column that have a matching Index Key into one cell for some columns, and select the most recently entered cell (can just be the first in that appears in list) to fill the cell in other columns.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Things I've tried but could definitely not have been doing correctly:

1. VLookUp in an array formula combined with join(text)
2. Query with ArrayFormula, but SQL and ArrayFormula don't like cooperating

**EDIT**
Link to reduced form of database: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if7FP-5cZRRLe1BliqYC35XtqhoqQAVoADNSVuqtGgs/edit#gid=1165169486

Comment: Provide some images, code, links, research materials, something apart from a wall of text.

Comment: I'm working on some reference material. Just a little difficult because there is confidential material within my source so I have to make a copy and then share.

Comment: I've added a link to the question but here is is again! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if7FP-5cZRRLe1BliqYC35XtqhoqQAVoADNSVuqtGgs/edit#gid=1165169486